# Display only directories names in one directory

Tags: php

I need display names directories in one directory. In dir I have directories and files, I need display directories only.

My code:

```
<?php
$szablony = opendir('libs');

while($katalog = $szablony ->read()){
    if(!is_dir($katalog))
    echo $katalog;
}

$szablony->close();
?>
```

This code display all: files and directories. I tried use is_dir() function but this function returns only directories:

```
.
..
```

Comment: Maybe its just me but I have a hard time understanding what you want. Do you want to see the directory names or not??

Comment: you may want to look into [iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Comment: I want display directory names without file names.

Comment: need to be if(is_dir($katalog)) omit the '!' not sign

Comment: so many duplicates in the Related secion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the path along with the name. Since you're opening up the libs/ directory, add `'libs/'` before `$katalog` in your `!is_dir()` call.

The way it's checking now is relative to where the script is. So if your script is at `/www/script.php`, and the `/www/libs/` directory has a "file.php" and "directory/" in it, what you're currently doing is checking on:

```
/www/file.php      //doesn't exist
/www/directory/    //doesn't exist
/www/..            //is a directory for /www/ as well
/www/.             //is a directory for /www/ as well
```

If you modify your check to be

```
if($katalog != '..' && $katalog != '.' && is_dir('libs/' . $katalog)
```